# How to initialize a class data member which is a std::set with custom comparator

Tags: c++, class, stl

I'm not quite sure what is the correct way to initialize an std set with custom comparator when it is a class data member. The following code give me compilation failure once I add the line to insert list iterator into the set. I'm not sure why.

```
#include <list>
#include <set>
#include <iterator>

auto pred = [](auto const& v1, auto const& v2) {
                *v1 < *v2;
            };
using LstIter = std::list<int>::iterator;

class MaxStack {
public:
    MaxStack()
        :valLst(),
         valSet(pred)
    {}

    void push(int x) {
        valLst.push_back(x);
        LstIter it = std::prev(valLst.end());

        // this line causes compile failure
        valSet.insert(it);
    }

  private:
    std::list<int> valLst;
    std::set<LstIter, decltype(pred)> valSet;    
};
```

Now the issue is I forgot to type return in lambda. I cannot believe it is case and I have been looking at the code for 10 mins and still didn't see it.

But a more interesting question is then, if that is mistake. Why compiler didn't error out during the class constructor code. while fail when I try to invoke comparator for the first time. shouldn't compiler check the comparator signature when constructing the set?

Comment: Show the exact and complete text of the error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
auto pred = [](auto const& v1, auto const& v2) {
                *v1 < *v2;
            };
```

Fixing this obvious fat-finger to what it should be:

```
auto pred = [](auto const& v1, auto const& v2) {
                return *v1 < *v2;
            };
```

Results in gcc 9 successfully compiling the shown code.

Comment: oh my god, I'm so embarrassed. I have been wondering for 10 mins trying to figure out what the heck is wrong. Of course, it never returns anything.

Comment: On the other hand though. Why the heck the compiler didn't error out for the constructor code. The construction of set obviously should fail, the expected comparator signature should return a bool.

Comment: Because `std::set` is a template. Template methods don't get instantiated until they are actually used. This is fundamental to how templates work. There's nothing in the constructor code that directly has to compare the values in the set, so the actual code that invokes the comparator never gets instantiated. But once you write the code that actually must do it, `std::set`'s internal template methods that compare the values in the set get instantiated and the compiler discovers a small problem... (you asked this as a follow after I wrote my answer, please write a new question next time).

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

`std::set` expects its comparator to return a `bool`. But `pred` is a `void` function, it doesn't actually return any value.